# basic beamerposter example, keyval error

Tags: beamerposter, key-value, posters, xkeyval

I found a beamerposter example at this url: http://www-i6.informatik.rwth-aachen.de/~dreuw/latexbeamerposter.php

The content suggests that a number of packages may be required, therefore, I use the nominated packages:

```
\usepackage{fp}
\usepackage{xkeyval}
\usepackage{type1cm}
\usepackage{paralist}
```

nnsuring that the each of these packages are up to date.  A number of beamer themes have been made available, one such example can be found here: http://www-i6.informatik.rwth-aachen.de/~dreuw/download/beamerthemeI6dv.sty

The example code is shown below.

poster.tex

```
\documentclass[final]{beamer}
\mode<presentation>
{%
\usetheme{I6dv}
}%
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{fp}
\usepackage{paralist}
\usepackage{xkeyval}
\usepackage{type1cm}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[orientation=landscape,%
size=custom,%
width=200,%
height=120,%
scale=1]{beamerposter}
\title[]{Poster Title}
\author{Author}
\institute[]{Institution}
\date{\today}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{} 
\vfill
\begin{block}{\large Fontsizes}
\centering
{\tiny tiny}\par
{\scriptsize scriptsize}\par
{\footnotesize footnotesize}\par
{\normalsize normalsize}\par
{\large large}\par
{\Large Large}\par
{\LARGE LARGE}\par
{\veryHuge veryHuge}\par
{\VeryHuge VeryHuge}\par
\end{block}
\vfill
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

When the theme is placed next to this .tex file and the .tex is compiled, I initially receive the following error:

```
! Package keyval Error: fg undefined
```

As far as my due diligence in trying to solve the problem, I found [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/81696/beamerposter-example-does-not-work), as well as, [this one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/74334/beamerposter-custom-style-with-keyval-definition).  I didn't find too much useful info in either.

When I search the error message, I find [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/139332/package-keyval-error-undefined-color-beamer), however, there wasn't really anything compelling in the thread.

I saw that the xkeyval is described as an *extension* to the keyval package, so I tried to include `\usepackage{keyval}` on the off change that (if in fact it existed) it was also required.  This idea didn't pan out.

Any comments/suggestions are greatly appreciated.  One option might be to locate a different poster example.

Comment: the problem is in the .sty file, lines 33 and 45, where it tries to set a color into a `\setbeamerfont` macro, which is used for font settings, not colors. Remove the color related options (line 33: `fg=white` and line 45:`bg=i6colorscheme1,fg=white`) and it will work. You'll also need the logo called at line 107 (or use the `demo` documentclass option)

Comment: @dcmst, I have implemented the suggested changes.  It now works like a charm.  Thanks!

Comment: @domenicocamasta would you like to convert your comment to an answer?

Comment: @daibowen done!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

the problem is in the .sty file, lines 33 and 45, where it tries to set a color into a `\setbeamerfont` macro, which is used for font settings, not colors.

Remove the color related options 
line 33: `fg=white` 
line 45:`bg=i6colorscheme1,fg=white`

and it will work. You'll also need the logo called at line 107 (or use the `demo` documentclass option)